# AngularJS trigger slide-toggle in Controller

Tags: angularjs, slidetoggle

I am using for my Slide up/down effect this genius written .js modul.
https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables

http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/19/

I could include it to my project and it is working the way I want.
But now I want to trigger this inside my controller, how do I do this?

html

```
<a href="" ng-click="Triggerhere();" slide-toggle="#derp">Open smoothly</a>

<div id="derp" class="slideable">
     open/hidden content
</div>
```

.js

```
var myApp  = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'angularSlideables']);

angular.module('angularSlideables', [])
.directive('slideable', function () {
    return {
       all the code from the github
    })


 myApp.controller("ContactControllerHeading", function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.Triggerhere= function() {
          /* trigger here this   slide-toggle="#derp" */
     }

  });
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: may be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0x22oL7u/) will help

Comment: looks like the same one as I posted

Answer (score 0):

I gave up solving it with this. I used jquery slide up and down function which seems to be a adequate solution

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp